# How to prevent reset date range in jQuery Date Range Picker?

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I have a simple date range picker, my first click and second click is okay it will show the date range both selected but in the third click the date range reset and back to default behavior. How can i prevent reset in the third or fourth  click i want the range of the date always show base on the selected date like Google flights.

**Google Flights:**
https://www.google.com/flights?gl=us&hl=en#flt=/m/0fn2g.HKG.2018-11-29*HKG./m/0fn2g.2018-12-04;c:THB;e:1;sd:1;t:f

```js
var options = {
  startOfWeek: 'monday',
  separator: ' ~ ',
  format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'
 };

$('#date-range0')
  .dateRangePicker(options)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-date-range-picker/0.14.4/daterangepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-date-range-picker/0.14.4/jquery.daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<input id="date-range0" size="40" value="">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ethan0007/1w7u8bno/